# Positioning information within container

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a progress bar in the white space below the centered logo. But since I am using container-fluid I cant use "align-items-end" because for some reason it extends the container height more. Can someone tell me how I should change this so I can add more information below the logo and not mess up the "Create" and "Explore" positioning?

```css
/*This css file defines the color scheme and font of all of the webpages so import into every new webpage*/

body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #161925;
  color:#FDFFFC;
}
h4{
  color:#FDFFFC;
}
.button{
    background-color:#F1D302;
}
```

```html
<link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
  <img src="/img/logo.png" width="100" height="140">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a href="#" name="redirectCreate" onClick="redirectCreate()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
              Create</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <a href="#" name="redirectExplore" onClick="redirectExplore()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
              Explore</h1>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="row">
    HI
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *"below the centered logo"* -- there's absolutely no indication in your code that the logo should be centered. So, I suggest you start there.

Answer (score 0):

When you "Run code snippet" the logo is not centered.

Although you could add `<center></center>` tags around whatever you want centered. or use `text-align:center` in your CSS for that class.